# Populate a div with text that has a specific css at a certain hour of the day

Tags: css, populate, hour

I am looking for a way to populate a div with text that has a specific css. I have two different css, and I want them to populate the div at certain time of the day. So: offline style for the night, online for the day. I am familiar with js but im looking for help as I want to combine "populate div" and "at certain time". And the neutral mode is empty of text - thats why I want it to be populated- I hope someone can help me! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Contain your css in two separate classes. Let's say class "Day" and class "Night".

Then add the following Javascript:

```
<script>

var d = new Date();
var t = d.getHours();

if((t =< 18)&(t >= 6)){
    //Day
    body.addClass('Day');
}
else{
    //Night
    body.addClass('Night');
}    

</script>
```